# Pass expression values as input parameter of function module

Tags: abap

I have a question about passing functions and expressions as actual parameters to function modules. 
 For study aim, I run a function module in which pass simple arithmetic expression (minus). There is a mistake "After '-' wait '=...'". The function module has one pass by value input parameter of type n. But in this article [link](http://www.consolut.com/en/s/sap-ides-access/d/s/doc/B-ABENTYPING_ARITH_EXPR) say that it possible. Maybe I have an old version of ABAP?
For example create function ZOUT, which write on screen its import parameter

```
FUNCTION ZOUT.
*"-----------------------------------------------------------------
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(SOMENUM) TYPE  N
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
  WRITE: / somenum.
ENDFUNCTION.
```

From some report call:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'ZOUT'
  EXPORTING
    somenum = ( ld_a - ld_b ).
```

Where `ld_a` and `ld_b` are local variables.

Version of ABAP - 702.

Comment: What version do you have? And why do you link to a 3rd party copy instead of the original documentation?

Comment: @IvanRyazanov Ok, now I get it. It is highly probable that your system is an older one. In my case the `SAP_ABA` component is Release 711, Level 0009, SP SAPKA71109. In the system I am working in, there is no problem in compiling such an expression.

Comment: @IvanRyazanov Could you try passing the expression to a method parameter instead of a function module and see if it works for you?

Comment: @Jagger, It has a same result, but return message look more valid : " The "Parameter "Somenum" cannot be passed the result of an arithmetic calculation"

Comment: @IvanRyazanov Try the example from this [part](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abentyping_arith_expr.htm) of SAP documentation. I guess in your case it is only possible to pass the expressions to so called functional methods (in other words calls without using CALL METHOD).

Comment: @Jagger, First release of my class differ from documentation only type of parameter: I use n, there - numeric. I changed and now it work.

Comment: @IvanRyazanov I am happy it worked for you. If you find my answer helpful then I would be happy if you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a system with `SAP_ABA` Release 740 SP-Level 004 SP SAPKA74004 I was able to do even such a thing without using brackets.

```
DATA: l_n1 TYPE n VALUE '3'.
DATA: l_n2 TYPE n VALUE '1'.

CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_INFORM'
  EXPORTING
    titel = l_n1 - l_n2
    txt1  = l_n2 - l_n1
    txt2  = l_n1 - l_n1.
```

However on a system with `SAP_ABA` Release 711, SP-Level 0009, SP SAPKA71109 it does **not** compile even with brackets.

```
DATA: l_n1 TYPE n VALUE '3'.
DATA: l_n2 TYPE n VALUE '1'.

CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_INFORM'
  EXPORTING
    titel = ( l_n1 - l_n2 )
    txt1  = ( l_n2 - l_n1 )
    txt2  = ( l_n1 - l_n1 ).
```

So, the answer to your question is: it looks like it is only possible in the brand new version of ABAP. Passing parameter values as expressions should be however possible with method calls in the older versions. Why using function modules anyway if there is quite nice ABAP OO, right? ;-)